# use paginate in livewire components

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-9

I have a component which looks like

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Comments;

use App\Models\Comment;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class ShowComments extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;
    protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';
    public $comments;

    public function getListeners()
    {
        return ['commentAdded'];
    }

    public function mount(){
        $this->comments = Comment::latest()->get();
    }

    public function commentAdded(){
        $this->comments = Comment::latest()->paginate(5);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.comments.show-comments');
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error when i try to use `paginate`.

`Livewire component's [comments.show-comments] public property [comments] must be of type: [numeric, string, array, null, or boolean]. Only protected or private properties can be set as other types because JavaScript doesn't need to access them.`

When the comment is added on the post I am firing an event from the `SinglePost` component to re-render the `ShowComments` component.

```
//emit the event to ShowComments component
$this->emit('commentAdded');
```

I am using the paginate method inside the render method of my `ShowPosts` component like

```
public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.posts.show-posts', [
        'posts' => Post::latest()->paginate(5)
    ]);
}
```

but doing this does not allow me to listen for events and refresh/re-render the components. Any workaround for this so I can use paginate with public properties?

Answer (score 0):

By Looking at your code I spotted some functional errors in ShowComments component.

Firstly the `$comments` is mounted with results retrieved from get() method, So Initially `$comments` holds Collection Object Data type. Later on when you update it in event Listener with `$this->comments = Comment::latest()->paginate(5);`,`$comments` is being modified to hold Paginate Object Data type.

That is the cause of error `Livewire component's [comments.show-comments] public property [comments] must be of type: [numeric, string, array, null, or boolean].`

If you wish to use Pagination for comments component then you must declare it in render method itself. Later on, when you need to refresh the comments with the event listener, you could simply call `$this->refresh()`. Which will refetch the comments and basically refresh the comments component.

You `ShowComments` Component should look something like this after above updates:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Comments;

use App\Models\Comment;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class ShowComments extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;
    protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';

    public function getListeners()
    {
        return ['commentAdded'];
    }

    public function commentAdded(){
        //refreshes ShowComments component
        $this->refresh();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.comments.show-comments',[
            'comments' => Comment::latest()->paginate(5)
        ]);
    }
}
```